# How to populate tiers in a Praat textgrid based on another text file?

Tags: praat, annotated-data

I created an excel file with the following columns: start_time, end_time, transcript, quotative, tag. The start_time and end_time columns indicate the boundaries of each interval. I turned this excel file into a tab-delimited text file.
What I'd like to do, based on this text file, is to generate a Textgrid in Praat (aligned with the audio), with three tiers : transcript, quotative, tag. There would be the same intervals across all tiers. The intervals on each tier would be populated with info coming from the corresponding columns in the text file (transcript, quotative, tag).

I've tried to find information on how to do that, but I don't manage. I find a lot of info on how to **export** data from a textgrid into a csv file, but I don't know how to **import** information into a textgrid, based on timestamps. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not linguistics. You need an Excel expert.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic.

Comment: Praat is a software programme used by linguists. I'm not sure an Excel expert will be able to help...

Comment: Maybe so but it is not a linguistics question. How to use a program is not linguistics.

Comment: That's strange because all questions related to Praat are to be found in "Linguistics", and that's actually how I ended up here.

Answer (score 0):

This requires some programming: there is no general point-and-click Excel option. [This](https://rdrr.io/cran/act/man/export_textgrid.html) may suffice for your purposes (i.e. if you can figure out what it does and what you are supposed to do to implement it). Otherwise, you would need to understand the structure of a textgrid file. [Here](https://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/TextGrid_file_formats.html) is a description of a textgrid file. There are actually two forms, the full form and the short form. The short form is basically a cvs file with separate lines rather than tabs.